# concatenating strings?

Tags: python, string

```
def change(s):
    s = s + "!"


word = "holiday"
change(word)    
print word
```

how come the output of this is "holiday" instead of "holiday!"? Is it because the 3 line of codes are outside the function? If so, why would it matter if it's outside the function since it's after the change function?

Comment: This explains your situation more generally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
def change(s):
    return s + "!"
```

Use it like this:

```
word = 'holiday'
print change(word)
```

Or like this:

```
word = 'holiday'
word = change(word)
print word
```

Be aware that any modifications you do to a parameter string inside a function will *not* be seen outside the function, as the `s` parameter in the function is local to the scope of the function, and any changes you do (like in the code in the question) will only be visible inside the function, not outside. All function parameters in Python are [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/201359).

Comment: @alicew you're welcome! please read the link in the last paragraph of my answer to fully understand what's happening with the string inside your function.

Comment: @alicew also, please don't forget to accept as correct (click the check mark to its left) the answer that was most helpful

Answer (score 3):

You are only modifying the local variable `s` in the function `change`. This does not modify the variable `word`. If you wish to modify `word`, you need to return the result of `change` and assign it to `word`:

```
def change(s):
    s = s + "!"
    return s


word = "holiday"
word = change(word)    
print word
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning the value from change.

Try:

```
def change(s):
    s = s + "!"
    return s


word = "holiday"
word = change(word)    
print word
```

So in the above example, s is being modified, and then word is reassigned the modified value.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a 'copy' of word rather that word instance to the function.  Therefore changes are applied to the copy of word you hold in s variable inside the function

Comment: Thats not true. python passes a reference to the value. He is just shadowing the variable with a local one

Comment: Thats more correct explanation; but in given scenario it helps to explain that as a result of shadowing and different scopes,  it appears that you are working on a copy

Comment: I agree that your answer is a simplification of the situation, but I still think its misleading to use the word copy. They are the same object inside and outside of the function. A string is mutable so there is no way to change it other than shadowing it and returning a new copy.

Comment: The "copy" happens in s = s + "!", not in the function call. Local s and global word refer to the same string before that line; after that line, s refers to a modified copy "holiday!". Your answer as written is dangerously misleading in Python, which is not a call-by-value language.

Comment: @jdi: I'm assuming you mean "a string is immutable" ;)

Comment: I know I ovsdsimplified to the point of potentially misleading.  Feel free to downvote.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Gah TYPO. IMmutable. And I wont downvote this. It was a comment-only situation :-)

Answer (score 1):

`s` in `change(s)` is a name that is bound to the value of `word` when you call `change(word)`.

In the line `s = s + "!"` you are binding `s` to a new string which is created by concatenating the value bound to `s` and `!`, not doing anything to `word`.

Also it is best not to have side effects even if it is possible so returning a new value is better.

```
def change(s):
    return s + '!'
```